# Query to get oldest record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

i have this following code:

```
;with cte as (
   Select RegardingObjectId , 
          DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, getutcdate(), getdate()),CreatedON) as [Time First Response] 
          from dbo.Email
    where DirectionCode = '1'
)
SELECT  dbo.Incident.new_CaseID as [CASE ID], 
        cte.RegardingObjectId, 
        dbo.Incident.IncidentId, 
        dbo.Incident.Title as [SUBJECT], 
        dbo.Incident.StatusCode as [STATUS], 
        cte.[Time First Response] 
from dbo.Incident
left Join cte on cte.RegardingObjectId = dbo.Incident.IncidentId
order by dbo.Incident.new_CaseID desc
```

this query will return a result like :
[image: Images]

As you can see, the query returning multiple records with same CASE ID. What i want is, for every multiple records have same CASE ID, only one with oldest [Time First Response] is retrieved

Comment: what are you using, `MySQL` or `SQL-Server`?

Comment: @Geoman Yabes: sorry, its sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your query in another `CTE` and use `ROW_NUMBER` to prioritize and get the oldest record per `[CASE ID]`:

```
;with cte as (
   Select RegardingObjectId , 
          DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, getutcdate(), getdate()),CreatedON) 
             as [Time First Response] 
          from dbo.Email
    where DirectionCode = '1'
), cte2 as (
   SELECT  dbo.Incident.new_CaseID as [CASE ID], 
           cte.RegardingObjectId, 
           dbo.Incident.IncidentId, 
           dbo.Incident.Title as [SUBJECT], 
           dbo.Incident.StatusCode as [STATUS], 
           cte.[Time First Response],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.Incident.new_CaseID
                              ORDER BY cte.[Time First Response]) AS rn
   from dbo.Incident
   left Join cte on cte.RegardingObjectId = dbo.Incident.IncidentId
)
SELECT [CASE ID],
       RegardingObjectId,
       IncidentId,
       [SUBJECT], 
       [STATUS], 
       [Time First Response]
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY [CASE ID] desc
```

Comment: The ORDER BY cte.[Time First Response] shouldn't be DESC, because he wants to get the "oldest" record ?.

Comment: @MarcGuillot `DESC` would fetch the *latest* record. This is what I initially had in my query but then I took a second look at the question.

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos : hiiiii, thanks. this is the answer i have been looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `MIN` function

```
;with cte as (
   Select RegardingObjectId , 
          DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, getutcdate(), getdate()),CreatedON) as [Time First Response] 
          from dbo.Email
    where DirectionCode = '1'
)
SELECT  dbo.Incident.new_CaseID as [CASE ID], 
        cte.RegardingObjectId, 
        dbo.Incident.IncidentId, 
        dbo.Incident.Title as [SUBJECT], 
        dbo.Incident.StatusCode as [STATUS], 
        cte.[Time First Response] 
from dbo.Incident
left Join cte on cte.RegardingObjectId = dbo.Incident.IncidentId
AND cte.[Time First Response] IN (SELECT MIN(cte.[Time First Response]) 
FROM cte WHERE cte.RegardingObjectId = dbo.Incident.IncidentId)
order by dbo.Incident.new_CaseID desc
```